# How To Render An Object In Django Views?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, beautifulsoup

I have a form that accepts URLs. This URL is then being parsed with BS4 and product created with the following class:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url = models.TextField()
    price = models.FloatField()
```

I want to save only unique products to the database. Therefore I added the following code into the *add* function in the *views.py* file to check the product by its ID:

```
def add(request):
    ...
    product.product_id = soup.find('h1', class_='product-id').text
    if Product.objects.filter(product_id=product.product_id):
        return render(request, 'product/add.html', {'error': 'Product already exists'})
    else:
        product.title = soup.find('h1', class_='product-name').text
        ...
        product.save()
        return redirect('/product/' + str(product.id))
```

Currently, user receives the 'Product already exists' error message. But I want to actually render the already existing product instead. Here is the function for detailed product:

```
def detail(request, product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    return render(request, 'product/detail.html', {'product': product})
```

The URL to detailed product looks like this: http://example.com/product/22
There is probably a better way to retrieve, compare and then render an object. Please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just redirect to the Product's defined get_absolute_url property?

```
def add(request):
    ...
    product.product_id = soup.find('h1', class_='product-id').text
    existing_product = Product.objects.filter(product_id=product.product_id)
    if existing_product:
        return redirect(existing_product.get_absolute_url())
```

Comment: Thank you. However it looks like we have to find another way to find an existing product, as right now I'm getting the following error: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'get_absolute_url'.

Comment: You need to define get_absoute_url in your model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url