# How To Correctly Define 'get_absoute_url' in Django?

Tags: python, django

Can you please help me to correctly define the **get_absolute_url**? Right now I'm been redirected to **'.../product/32949492331'**, however the url should look like: **'.../product/1'**, **'.../product/2'**, etc. 
Here is **models.py**:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url = models.TextField()
    price = models.FloatField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail', kwargs={'product_id': self.product_id})
```

**views.py:**

```
def detail(request, product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    return render(request, 'product/detail.html', {'product': product})
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('add', views.add, name='add'),
    path('<int:product_id>', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

This is a follow up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55670417/how-to-render-an-object-in-django-views). Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It seems that you are mixing things up a little bit. Unless `product_id` is marked as `primary_key=True` (which in the posted model it is not) you should call `reverse()` passing `self.id` and not `self.product_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, you have:

```
return reverse('detail', kwargs={'product_id': self.product_id})
```

So if that returns a url with `32949492331`, that’s because the `product_id` field for that object is `32949492331`.

Perhaps you want to use the product’s primary key instead:

```
return reverse('detail', kwargs={'product_id': self.pk})
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely, mixed them up. However, I tried to use both self.id and self.pk and I'm getting a 'NoReverseMatch' error: 'Reverse for 'detail' with keyword arguments '{'product_id': None}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['product/(?P<product_id>[0-9]+)$']'. I actually don't mind to set the product_id as an url. Can you advise me how to do that?

Comment: I can't see how that `get_absolute_url` would give that error with `self.pk`, unless you are calling `product.get_absolute_url()` on a product that has not been saved yet.

Comment: If you wanted to use the `product_id` field in the URLs, you would switch back to `{'product_id': self.product_id}` in `get_absolute_url`, then use `product = get_object_or_404(Product, product_id=product_id)` in the `detail` view. Note that `<int:product_id>` may not work with all `product_id`s in your database, (e.g. if you have a `product_id` which contains letters/symbols, or a `product_id` that starts with `0`.